# Error: Sharepoint 2010 Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, chart

I have a sp2010 website where I am trying to use a network path for the images as I have a WebFarm which is loadBalanced using CISCO ACE appliance hardware (without IP Stickiness). The reason I am using a network shared folder is that at times the Chart does not show the PNG images. I am using UpdatePanel with Timer to update the chart every minute

The problem with displaying the PNG images in the Web Farm comes when I had initially the web.config setting as shown below.

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=10;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

So I used the network Shared path as per the article, where I have FULL Permissions on EVERYONE, NETWORK Service.

Below is my current setting for the Network shared folder path and I keep getting this error: Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=10;dir=\\servername\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

Can someone help.

Rgds,

SSP

Answer (score 1):

I just tried and it might sound like a crazy idea, why don't you map the remote folder as a local drive, this way it will just be seen as a local file by anything but windows.

Seems to work on a non load balanced server I don't see why it wouldn't mapped on each of your servers.

(This is presuming permissions are right and you can browse to x:\foo\bar once mapped on any user account)